# Simulating virtual methods in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am writing a Delphi interface for SSE instructions. It's a class (for visibility sake, etc) TSimdCpu with N class methods (one per each SSE instruction; the obvious performance overhead is not an issue right now).

Now I want to compare performance of my code (slow as it is) with pure pascal code doing same thing. My first guess would be to write a similar class TGenericCpu with same method names. But without the common base class and virtual methods I can't just have one piece of testing code that would call methods of whatever class it's supposed to run tests on.
Ideally, I would like something like

```
TestOn(TSimdCpu);
TestOn(TGenericCpu);
```

But I am lost on how to implement this **without** using delphi's virtual methods. **I don't want** to fall back to virtual methods for two reasons: one is performance and another is that it's only going to be used for testing and for all practical use it would be adding meaningless complexity.

Can generics be useful here? Something like

```
TTest<T> = class
...
T.AddVector(v);
...
TTest<TSimdCpu>.Test;
TTest<TGenericCpu>.Test;
```

Comment: Re "*performance*": Please verify your code (once completed) is really faster that a simple virtual method call. Re "*meaningless complexity*": How would you like to call what you are doing here and how much time do you want to spend for an project that is "*only going to be used for testing*"?

Comment: I'd call it "reaching delphi's limits". Any amount of time that I'm not doing "tractor coding" is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to implement something that looks like virtual methods but does not use virtual methods or interfaces for performance reasons.

You need to add some indirection. Create a record that holds procedural variables. For illustration:

```
type
  TAddFunc = function(a, b: Double): Double;

  TMyRecord = record
    AddFunc: TAddFunc;
  end;
```

Then declare two instances of the record. One populated with the SSE functions, and one populated with the non-SSE reference functions.

At this point you have what you need. You can pass these records around and use the indirection they provide to write generic test code.

This indirection will cost though. After all, what you have here is a manual implementation of interfaces. Expect a similar performance overhead for function call as for interfaces.

I expect that, unless your operands are large arrays, that the indirection cost will skew your benchmarks. I know that you asked specifically how to implement the tests using indirection, but I personally would want to test using as close to the real code as possible. That means testing direct function calls.

---

You ask about generics. They are no use to you. In order to make a generic class that was parameterised on the class under test, you'd need the class under test to be derived from a common base class, or implement a common interface. And then you are back where you started.

Comment: Can generics be any help?

Comment: Sadly not. I don't think you are going about this the right way. I'd have a conditional that switches compilation between variants. I believe that you need to remove runtime redirection.

Comment: This is just re-creating a VMT. So IMHO speed benefit from a regular virtual method would only for one lookup. And if you define your methods as `class procedure` instead of `procedure`, the class virtual methods and the VMT-record-trick will perform exactly the same.

Comment: @Arnaud Indeed. Asker wants to avoid virtual methods but have the same functionality. So hardly surprising that you end up with a reimplementation of virtual methods. Not a good idea. I said all this didn't I? I'm would simply not do it this way. I'd call methods directly without indirection.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the main speed difference won't be between function calls.

If you take a look at the asm, a virtual method call is something like

```
mov eax,object
mov ebx,[eax]  // get the the class info VMT
call dword ptr [ebx+##] // where ## is the virtual method offset
```

Whereas a non virtual method is

```
mov eax,object
call SomeAbsoluteAddress
```

And for a pointer to a function (on the stack)

```
mov eax,object
call dword ptr [ebp+##] // where ## is the pointer in the stack
```

You are just gaining one or two lookups in the class info VMT.

I suspect your test are over-optimized for the pointer to a function, since the pointer is probably on the stack. On real code, you would have to store the pointer somewhere, so you would gain nothing in comparison to a virtual method call.

And if you define your methods as `class procedure` instead of `procedure`, I suspect the class virtual methods and the function redirection will perform exactly the same:

```
mov eax,classinfo
call dword ptr [eax+##] // where ## is the virtual method offset
```

For such calculation, what would *really speed up the process* may be not calling functions at all, but creating some kind of simple JIT. Create the binary opcode flow before running the function, by looking at the asm opcodes, then create a buffer containing the execution flow, and directly execute it. Here we would talk about performance. It is similar to *inlining* function calls.

I know at least two (recent and maintained) projects with such JIT compilation written in Delphi: [Besen JavaScript engine](https://code.google.com/p/besen/) and [Delphi Web Script](https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/browse/trunk/Source/jitter/). Besen copies asm stubs to create the JITted buffer, whereas DWS computes the opcodes via a set of generator methods.

Also consider using a language with tuned and optimized JIT if you need floating point performance. You could use e.g. our Open Source [SpiderMonkey library for Delphi](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynSM.pas). You could write your code in plain JavaScript, then let the optimized JIT do its work. You may be amazed by the resulting speed: the result is [usually faster than Delphi x87 native code](http://www.delphitools.info/2011/03/24/kudos-to-the-firefox-4-tracemonkey-team/), for floating point. You would gain a lot of development time.

Comment: It's a little unfair to compare anything against an ancient 32 bit compiler. How about comparing against the modern, now mature 64 bit compiler.

Comment: Why don't you actually test speed of virtual function call. Your assumptions about "one or two lookups" is wrong. My code is here. There is nothing to suspect there.

Comment: I checked the asm. Did you try to use a class method? It is the same as a function pointer in a record. You did not supply any code, which I suppose is unfair.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez It is unclear who that comment is addressed to

Answer (score 0):

David Heffernan's idea seems like the only way for now. I did a quick test - here are the results:

```
simd 516 ms (pointer to a function, asm)
JensG 1187 ms (virtual method, asm)
generic 2797 ms (pointer to a function, pascal)
generic virtual 3360 ms (virtual method, pascal)
```

The difference between normal and virtual function calls could be relatively small for pascal code, but not for asm

```
  if cpu = nil then
    if test.name = 'JensG' then
      for i := 1 to N do begin
        form1.JensGAdd(v1^);
        form1.JensGMul(v2^);
      end
    else
      for i := 1 to N do begin
        form1.GenericAdd(v1^);
        form1.GenericMul(v2^);
      end
  else
    for i := 1 to N do begin
      cpu.AddVector(v1^);
      cpu.MulVector(v2^);
    end;
```

Comment: Actually, he could put each class in its own include and then test separately. IOW, simply copy-and-paste polymorphism. After all, this is just for a simple test.

Comment: Why bother with includes when you can just change unit name in the uses clause

Comment: @Anton Chaning the unit name is exactly what I would do. I'd use a unit alias.